# XFS problem in IE, anyone know a better workaround?

Tags: security, internet-explorer

IE leaks keyboard events across frames, which causes a security concern.
The only recommendation I have found against this is to check if the content in the iframe is the topmost window, otherwise make it the topmost window.

`if(top!=self)top.location=self.location;`

Does anyone know of a better workaround?

Here is a link to the Public Advisory against the issue, it is quite old...
http://labs.idefense.com/intelligence/vulnerabilities/display.php?id=77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more reliable approach to preventing your site from being framed is to use the [X-Frame-Options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx) header. The link discusses clickjacking, but the countermeasure also applies to your question because the attack would require a malicious web site to frame your own site in order to start sniffing key events. (The link also points back to a coding horror article that describes the difficulties of JavaScript-based frame busting approaches.)

Here's some [more background](http://seclab.stanford.edu/websec/framebusting/) on frame busting. It includes a JavaScript-based technique, but prefers the X-Frame-Options method.